# JS JSON not parsed by PHP json_decode

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have an issue with parsing JSON data by json_decode PHP function. The issue is that the JSON I receive is not properly formatted. It looks as follows:

```
"{ user:1 ,product:4 ,commentCount: 1 ,comment:'All fine! Well done.' ,commentDate:{ year:2015 ,month:8 ,day:19 } , likes:8 }"
```

When I try to decode this string with json_decode PHP function I get NULL.
Is it possible to properly format this string with a preg_replace function

**EDIT:**
I found this code on the web but it only wraps the variable names in the quotes. The values are still as they were and json_decode still returns NULL.

```
// fix variable names
$PHPJSON = preg_replace( '/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+?):/' , '"$1":', $PHPJSON );
```

Comment: This is a not a valid json

Comment: Yes, I know. The question is if it is possible to format it correctly with the use of preg_replace?

Comment: Format it correctly where you create it in Javascript

Comment: I do not create it. I receive it from a third party. I am not able to change it before receiving.

Comment: Thats what I expected, you should at least tell them of their error though, maybe they will fix it

Comment: The problem with creating a fix for this specific returned JSON String is, **will it work for everything I want from this dodgy source** Do you mind saying where you get it from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working solution for your malformed json:

```
$json = "{ user:1 ,product:4 ,commentCount: 1 ,comment:'All fine! Well done.' ,commentDate:{ year:2015 ,month:8 ,day:19 } , likes:8 }";

$json = preg_replace('/(,|\{)[ \t\n]*(\w+)[ ]*:[ ]*/','$1"$2":',$json);
$json = preg_replace('/":\'?([^\[\]\{\}]*?)\'?[ \n\t]*(,"|\}$|\]$|\}\]|\]\}|\}|\])/','":"$1"$2',$json);

var_dump($json);

var_dump(json_decode($json));
```

But in general you need to wrap object param in double quotes `"arg":1`. Non-numeric values also. Just like this:

```
var_dump(json_decode('{"user":1}'));
var_dump(json_last_error());
```

The second function returns you id of an error, if there was any.
Check the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) for error codes identification

Comment: He knows it is not well formed JSON, this is not an answer

Comment: Updated my answer with solution

Comment: Thats nice -1 removed

Comment: Thanks but I have already checked the PHP manual. The issue still persists though - the JSON is still wrongly formatted.

Comment: Do you used preg_replace's from my answer? On PHP 5.4 works just fine.

Comment: WOW! I have no idea what it does but it works like a charm!